# Inverse Ackermann Function

Tags: computability-theory, inequalities

The inverse Ackermann function is defined over the natural numbers as follows: ($[x]$ means that we round up x to the nearest integer, while $\log^*$ is the iterated log function discussed here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_logarithm)
$$\alpha_1(n) = [n/2]$$
$$\alpha_2(n) = [\log_2 n]$$
$$\alpha_3(n) = \log^* n$$
$$...$$
$$\alpha_k(n) = 1 + \alpha_k(\alpha_{k−1}(n))$$ 
and $$\alpha(n) = \min\{k: \alpha_k(n)\leq 3\}$$
The question is what is $\beta(n)=\min\{k:\alpha_k(n)\leq \alpha(n)\}$?
In particular, is $\beta(n)\ll \log\alpha(n)$?

Comment: It is worth mentioning you are (probably) getting this from http://www.gabrielnivasch.org/fun/inverse-ackermann

Comment: Also posted here: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/30888/fun-with-inverse-ackermann

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, only noticed your question right now.

The function $\beta$ you define satisfies $\alpha(n)-2\le \beta(n) \le \alpha(n)$, since $\alpha_{\alpha(n)-3}(n)$ grows much faster than $\alpha(n)$ (though obviously slower than $\alpha_k(n)$ for any fixed $k$). Indeed, $\alpha_{\alpha(n)-3}(n) > A(\alpha(n)-2)$ where $A$ is the Ackermann function.

The five-line proof of this latter inequality is given on page 3 of my [PhD thesis](http://www.gabrielnivasch.org/academic/publications/phd_thesis.pdf), and on page 11 of the [arXiv version](http://arxiv.org/abs/0812.5039) of my paper with Bukh and Matoušek "Lower bounds for weak epsilon-nets and stair-convexity" (*Israel J. Math.* 182:199-228, 2011). (In these two references you can also find an application of the fact that $\alpha_{\alpha(n)-3}(n)\to\infty$.)